# how to remove css using jquery without specify the full file name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement of removing css file if it contains **jquery** in the name.

so if any css file for eg: jquerycustom.css , it should be removed from reference.

so how to extend the below to achieve my requirement?

```
$(this).removeClass('someClass');
```

Comment: You want to remove the file reference or css class from elements?

Comment: i want to remove the file reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("link[href*=jquery][rel=stylesheet]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

OR

```
$("link[href*=jquery][rel=stylesheet]").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I did't understand your question well, but if you want to remove multiple CSS class using `.removeClass`. you can use like this:

```
$("#element").removeClass("class1 class2");
```

OR Using regexp :

```
$("#element").removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/\bcolor-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xS/468/)

And If you want to remove CSS file :

Give an `id` to the `<link>` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" id="style1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" id="style2" />
```

And use this code:

```
$("#style1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Updated:

```
$("link[id*="jquery"][rel=stylesheet]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: OP said _"if it contains **jquery** in the name"_ - and was talking about the file name, not the class name.